# Why divide y value by 2

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've seen a few xCode projects that divide the height of an item by 2 in order to calculate the y coordinate for position. Something like this

```
CGFloat logoY = floorf((navBarHeight - logo.size.height) / 2.0f);
```

Why is it necessary to divide by 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Stonz2 said this code centers logo vertically. But it is better to use [autolayout constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to do so. Also do not forget that UIView has 'center' property which could be more convenient here. For example following code

```
CGFloat logoX = floorf((navBarWidth - logo.size.width) / 2.0f);
CGFloat logoY = floorf((navBarHeight - logo.size.height) / 2.0f);
logo.frame.origin = CGPointMake(logoX, logoY);
```

is equivalent to

```
logo.center =  CGPointMake(floorf(navBarWidth / 2), floorf(navBarHeight / 2));
```

Comment: so have you added the autolayout constraints in that code? or are you suggesting it be done in storyboard to add autolayout?

Comment: @Leahcim 'center' property is not autolayout constraint. Autolayout constraints could be added via IB or code. Please read more here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Center vertically. Otherwise it would be placed against the bottom of the view.

Comment: Of course its worth pointing out that it's better to use auto-layout constraints in this day and age as then you are defining constraints for all of your UI elements rather than bypassing auto-layout just to get something as trivial as centering.  The only place this is really useful is if you are trying to define something in a layer mask like a popup indicator.  In addition you don't even need to divide by two as UIView has a `center` property.